# Episerver - Consolidate Parent Page Folder/Media Folder as 1 Content Reference Property

Tags: episerver

I have an existing Content Reference Page property that points to parent page within episerver site.

```
[CultureSpecific]
        [Display(
            Name = "Parent Page",
            Description = "Select a parent page to display links to all of its subpages.",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 10)]
        public virtual ContentReference ParentPage { get; set; }


 @if (Model.ParentPage != null)
        {
            @Html.MenuList(Model.ParentPage,
                        @<text>
                            @foreach (var menuItem in item)
                                         {
                                <li class="link-list__item">
                                    <a class="link-list__link" href="@Url.ContentUrl(menuItem.Page.ContentLink)" target="@menuItem.Target">@menuItem.Page.Name</a>
                                </li>
                                         }
                        </text>)
        }
```

Helper class

```
   public static IHtmlString MenuList(this HtmlHelper helper, ContentReference rootLink, Func<List<MenuItem>, IHtmlString> itemTemplate, bool requireVisibleInMenu = true, bool requirePageTemplate = true, bool needsThirdLevel = false)
        {
            rootLink = rootLink ?? ContentReference.StartPage;

            var currentContentLink = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.GetContentLink();

            var pagePath = _contentLoader.Service.GetAncestors(currentContentLink)
                .Reverse()
                .Select(x => x.ContentLink)
                .SkipWhile(x => !x.CompareToIgnoreWorkID(rootLink))
                .ToList();

            var menuItems = _contentLoader.Service.GetChildren<PageData>(rootLink)
                .FilterForDisplay(requirePageTemplate, requireVisibleInMenu)
                .Select((model, index) => CreateMenuItem(model, currentContentLink, pagePath, requirePageTemplate, requireVisibleInMenu, needsThirdLevel, index))
                .ToList();

            return itemTemplate(menuItems);
        }
```

As an enhancement, I want to modify this property to not just handle **Page** as it is right now but also **Media files.** .

PS: I know the straight forward approach is to go with a totally different property with UIHint set to Media Folder. However, on a high level if we look at it, both the property is going to point to a folder (page/media).Its just the way it is going to select the folder for content/media differs & hence looking for a more generic way to handle this.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name and description of your `ParentPage` property would be misleading, but since it's already a `ContentReference` property it can handle any `IContent` type.

You could add an `AllowedTypes` attribute to explicitly specify which types of content can be set.

The user can then use the content picker (or drag-and-drop) to set the property to *either* a page or media.

Unless it's supposed to be able to handle *any* type of link, in which case you could consider changing to a `LinkItem` property.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ted.The problem with using LinkItem property is ,I'll have to add files individually whereas with Content Reference I can just point out the main parent folder which on looping will get me all the items within the Parent folder.